# Connect oracle to SAS

Tags: oracle, sas

Is there any way to connect from Oracle to SAS? 
In our company they are implemented SAS. SAS will be only way to connect every other database. My database in Oracle are linked with other Oracle DB from I get data. Now when I want data from this DB I need to uses SAS to do it...
So I look for solution to connect with this DB from my Oracle DB, but using SAS.

Comment: How is your SAS installation set up?  SAS Grid or server environment, or is this local SAS installations?

Comment: Do you mean a way to have Oracle job read data from a SAS dataset and load it to Oracle?

Comment: @Quentin The way I read this, OP wants to have an Oracle DB read from another Oracle DB, but the site is using SAS Metadata Server to manage rights access, meaning OP's oracle DB isn't allowed to just connect to the other Oracle; it has to go through the SAS MDS (presumably accessing a defined connection there).  I'm curious if Roger actually might be the best person to answer this, as it's not all that far off some of his use cases if I remember right...

Comment: @joe Exactly. This is my problem. Do you have any solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular SAS libnames where you provide your username (&user), password (&pw), path (&path) and schema (&schema):

libname oasis ORACLE path=&path. user=&user. pw=&pw. schema=&schema;

or you can connect using SQL directly:

```
proc sql;
    connect to oracle (path=&path. user=&user. password=&pw.);
        SQL_code;
    disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

Comment: but this is SAS->Oracle... I need Oracle->SAS